# ¿Cómo imprimir que fecha está o no está? - PHP

Tags: php, date

me he atorado nuevamente con esta secuencia en PHP

Tengo un rango de fechas, dentro de esas fechas faltan X días.
Necesito obtener que días faltan y cuales no, pero imprimirlos con el dato en orden. Ej:

> -este dia si falta 
> -este dia no falta 
> -este dia no falta 
> -este dia si falta

Actualmente he logrado obtener Todos los dias, los días que faltan, y realizar un merge de todos los días, para obtenerlos a todos. Ahora quiero saber cuales faltan, y que aparezcan en orden.

```
<?php
$finicial = "2021-07-01";//Rango inicial
$ffinal = "2021-07-10";//Rango final

$begin = new DateTime($finicial); //Inicio
$end = new DateTime($ffinal); //Fin
$end = $end->modify('+1 day'); //Ultimo dia
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D'); //Intervalo de 1 dia
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end); //Rango de fechas
$fechas = []; //array para guardar fechas
foreach ($daterange as $date) {
    $f = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date->format("Y-m-d"));
    array_push($fechas, $f->format("Y-m-d"));
}

$array = [ //Array con datos actuales, faltan dias
    "2021-07-01",
    "2021-07-02",
    "2021-07-04",
    "2021-07-05",
    "2021-07-07",
    "2021-07-08",
    "2021-07-10",
];

$diff = array_diff($fechas, $array); //Los días que faltanç
$todos = array_merge($diff, $array); //Todos los dias juntos
sort($todos); //Se ordenan los dias
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puse un ciclo que recorre el vector y verifica si un elemento esta o no:

```
<?php

$finicial = "2021-07-01";//Rango inicial
$ffinal = "2021-07-10";//Rango final

$begin = new DateTime($finicial); //Inicio
$end = new DateTime($ffinal); //Fin
$end = $end->modify('+1 day'); //Ultimo dia
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D'); //Intervalo de 1 dia
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end); //Rango de fechas
$fechas = []; //array para guardar fechas
foreach ($daterange as $date) {
    $f = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date->format("Y-m-d"));
    array_push($fechas, $f->format("Y-m-d"));
}

$array = [ //Array con datos actuales, faltan dias
    "2021-07-01",
    "2021-07-02",
    "2021-07-04",
    "2021-07-05",
    "2021-07-07",
    "2021-07-08",
    "2021-07-10",
];

$diff = array_diff($fechas, $array); //Los días que faltanç
$todos = array_merge($diff, $array); //Todos los dias juntos
sort($todos); //Se ordenan los dias

// Ciclo para recorrer los elementos del array
foreach ($todos as $element) {
    if (in_array($element, $array)) {
        echo $element.' -este día no falta. ';
    }else{
        echo $element.' -este día si falta. ';
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Los invertiste pero si, es esa la respuesta, solo corrige el IF para que los muestre correctamente. Luego de haber posteado esto, me di cuneta de como era XD

Comment: @Excorpion, listo corregido